# How do i mount a Raid disk in linux

Tags: mount

I have an ubuntu server that i had to restart on rescue mode and i am trying to mount a partition to reset the root password. I followed the instruction of the hosting company but got stuck and haven heard from them

When i try to do

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/
```

i got this error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

This is the output of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009307f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    20973568    10485760+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2        20973569  1952468992   965747712   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3      1952468993  1953520064      525536   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/md2: 988.9 GB, 988925591552 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 241436912 cylinders, total 1931495296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 10.7 GB, 10737352704 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 2621424 cylinders, total 20971392 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

How can i mount the disk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your RAID devices are called `/dev/md1` and `/dev/md2`.  It's possible that these contain your filesystems; you could try:

```
mount /dev/md1 /mnt
```

Or:

```
mount /dev/md2 /mnt
```

Depending on how your system is configured it is also possible that these devices are themselves part of a larger virtual device.  If you're unable to mount the individual devices, let us know and we'll work from there.

For more information about Linux software RAID, start with [this document](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Software-RAID-HOWTO.html).

Comment: i tried the first option and it seemed to work, but when i tried to use the password (after i reboot the server in non-rescue mode) the pass didnt work. Should i try on the second one (md2) ?

Comment: I have no idea what the relationship is between "the password" and these devices, nor can I tell you whether you should use `md1` or `md2`.  Your best bet is to confer with whoever set up this server.

Comment: well, i tried `md2` and could not change the root password there. I did it again on `md1` but the root password still does not work. How can i reset it?

Comment: @Jon How are you trying to change the root password? If you're mounting the drive and doing `passwd`, it's not going to work, since you are only changing the password for the running instance of the rescue cd OS.

Comment: i mounted the drive, then did chroot /mnt/, and then passwd root. which are the instructions from my hosting company. is that not the right way?

Comment: Folks, this discussion is really starting to stray from the original "how do I mount the disk" question.  It sounds like you should really be discussing this with your hosting company, or at the very least opening a new question.

Comment: I agree, I will open a new one

Answer (score 6):

I recently found a way to complete this and it's not too complicated.

I found this article, which helped out considerably.
https://ahelpme.com/linux/recovering-md-array-and-mdadm-cannot-get-array-info-for-dev-md0/

I ran these commands and had success.

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose

sudo cat /proc/mdstat
```

once you figure out which disk you want to mount...

```
mount /dev/md# /mnt/point
```